# C - recvfrom and signal

Tags: c, sockets, udp, signals

I want to handle SIGUSR1 signal so I do everything what it needs and it´s working. But in my program I am waiting at recvfrom and when I handle signal and return then to recvfrom I got -1 from this function. Is it possible to return back to waiting at this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system call is being [interrupted](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html#Interrupted-Primitives) by the signal. Unless you are consistently setting up signal handlers using `sigaction` with the [`SA_RESTART`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flags-for-Sigaction.html) flag, it is a good idea to retry system calls using a loop such as:

```
while ((size = recvfrom(...)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR` then you should attempt to call it again, or use the `SA_RESTART` flag when setting the signal handler, that should allow `recvfrom` to be restarted when it's interrupted by a signal.

From the man signal(7) page:

> If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted
>   by a signal handler, **then the call will be automatically restarted
>   after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used**; otherwise the call will fail with the error EINTR:
>
> Socket interfaces: accept(2),
>   connect(2), recv(2), **recvfrom(2)**, recvmsg(2), send(2), sendto(2), and
>   sendmsg(2), unless a timeout has been set  on  the socket (see below)

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I choose second one because when I set SA_RESTART flag it is waiting until recvfrom got data then execute commands in handler and then continue in executing rest of code and I need execude code in handler immediately after get signal. But thanks to you too.

Comment: @Bibo it's okay, but AFAIK it shouldn't, how do you set the flag ? I suppose you're using `sigaction` right ?

Comment: ´sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART´ And don´t know if it´s different but I am using FreeBSD.

Comment: @Bibo are you setting a timeout on the socket ? with `setsockopt` ? if not, yes it could be different on BSD, check the man page on your system.

Comment: Nope, not setting a timeout.